# Sails, NodeJS, Sqlite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sails.js

I'm working on a webapplication using [Sails](http://sailsjs.org).
It works fine with Postgres but I have to work with Sqlite.
I try the adapter [sails-sqlite3](https://github.com/AndrewJo/sails-sqlite3) but it doesn't work for me.

I would like to know if anyone has used Sails and Sqlite. And how ?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: When I try "sails lift" I have a version error concerning the function : registerCollection so I rename it registerConnection after that there was several error that I tried to correct.  Now there is problem between the adapter and the sqlite3 module:
node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:28
                    throw err;
                          ^
TypeError: string is not a function
    at .../api/adapters/sqlite3/lib/adapter.js:610:16
The line: return cb(err, result);
 I really think that the adapter is old so it can't work with my sails version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. 
Finally I just used waterline-nedb module and saved my database with .db extension
That seems great.

Comment: Did you need to refactor any of your code? I ask because it appears `nedb` is a document oriented DB like mongo while Postgres and Sqlite3 are relational.

Answer (score 0):

The sails-sqlite adapter is still in development as of 6-15-2015:

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-adapter-boilerplate/pull/3